# Python: how to create a dictionary from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I want to perform personlized pagerank (ppr) in python using `networkx` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196867/using-pythons-networkx-to-compute-personalized-page-rank)

I have a dataframe that contains the edgelist between two nodes `i` and `j`

```
df
     i     j
0    A     B
1    B     C
2    B     A
3    C     A
4    C     B
```

and for each node I have a label `0` or `1`.

```
dfN 
      Node  Label
0      A     0
1      B     1
2      C     0
```

I created the network

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'A', 'B')
```

Now I want to run the ppr

```
ppr1 = nx.pagerank(g,personalization={A:0, B:1, C:0})
```

How can I create the `dict` `{A:0, B:1, C:0}` directly from `dfN`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built method [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0], index=[0, 1, 2,3]).to_dict()
Out[39]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0}
```